# Beautifulsoup: extracting links from a file that links were already taken from

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write a web searching algorithm and on my first time through the site, I call beautifulsoup on it. I then use find_all on it and it returns a list of "a" class. Within this a class, there is a collection of data, but i'm trying to create of list of the URLs.  Here's my code:

```
soupcurrent = BeautifulSoup(html_current, 'html.parser')
search_results = soupcurrent.find_all(["a"], class_="XYZ")
```

After having run this, how do I pare the data down again to make a list of just the url?  In the format href="..."

I have tried already to use

```
     newlist.append(search_results.get('href')
```

but this hasn't worked.  any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `__getitem__` method of each tag object and pass `'href'`:

```
soupcurrent = BeautifulSoup(html_current, 'lxml')
search_results = soupcurrent.find_all("a", class_="XYZ")
urls = [i['href'] for i in search_results]
```

Edit:

To extract the image `src`, target the `img` tag and then access `"src"`:

```
s = '<div class="XYZ" data-imgid="000" id="000"><img alt=" 1" src="XYZ.jpg"; title=" 1"/></div>'
the_src = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml').find('img')['src']
```

Output:

```
'XYZ.jpg'
```

Comment: thanks, this does answer the question. but I'm realizing I think  I don't fully understand what Beautifulsoup is doing.  for example, i run soup.findall on another aspect of my code and it returns something of the form [div class="..." data-id="..." src="abc.com"]. this is a collection of data, what's the general way to get at something in the collection?  I did try data["src"] to try and get abc.com but it didn't work.                                                        one other question: when I try and get the page title it will return <Title>XYZ</title>. how do i just get the XYZ?

Comment: @Ryan `BeautifulSoup` is not returning strings, but rather a list of `BeautifulSoup` objects (instances of the class). To grab specific objects in the collection, it may be best to scrape the elements by class first, to know specifically what the list will be containing after. However, you can just index the list to find the specific content. Regarding the page title, to access the content itself, just call the `find.text` attribute i.e `(BeautifulSoup('<Title>XYZ</title>', 'lxml').find('title').text`

Comment: what am i doing wrong in this scenario:  i'm trying to get the price into a variable.    price = soup.find(class_="price")   . if i do this i get: <span class="price">$95</span> , so then I try price = soup.find(class_="price").text, or .contents, or .next, and I get an error message: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next' or 'text', etc.

Comment: @Ryan instead of `soup.find(class_="price")`, try: `soup.find('span', {'class':'price'}).text`

Comment: Also, really having trouble with this. Sorry for asking so many questions, this just isn't clicking for some reason :'( .    I'm running image = soup.find(class_= "XYZ") and then it returns of the form: <div class="XYZ" data-imgid="000" id="000"><img alt=" 1" src="https://XYZ.jpg" title=" 1"/></div>       how do I alter this to extract the link https://XYZ.jpg ?  I've tried soup.find(class_="XYZ", {"src" : ""}) but get an error with this.

Comment: why would you do a .find for "span" instead of being more specific with a class search off the bat?

Comment: @Ryan I apologize for the confusion. A direct `.find` for "span" is the best approach for your smaller example posted, however, for longer `html`, you would search for a more specific tag. Please see my recent edit for a solution to find the `src`. It appears that you are trying to solve multiple problems in just a few steps. With `BeautifulSoup`, you have to break down the task you are trying to complete into smaller parts that can be solved separately. It may also be helpful for you to explore an in-depth tutorial regarding `BeautifulSoup`: goo.gl/NVqiFM

Comment: @Ajax1234 thanks for the link, I will read through it, and thanks for your help with the above src, i was able to get that working.  Any advice on how to search for strings within a webpage? say the body was something like "I am learning how to use beautifulsoup".  I figured out how to isolate the body of the page and wrote it to "page_text".  I am then trying to search for a word or words within that.  I've tried: page_text.find(string="learning") but this seems to return an empty object "[]" when I run the code. any ideas?

Comment: my goal is basically to search for the word and have it return whether or not that word is in the body.I also tried page_text.find_all(string=re.compile('learning')), but also getting a "[ ]" return. i think it's not searching properly, because if i try an if true statement it will never go into that clause even though I know "learning" is in the document